# Collection as combination

Tags: word-choice

Is **collection** a good substitute for **combination** in:

They say wisdom is **a collection of** truth and beauty.

Comment: No: [**combine**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/combine) and [**collect**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/collect) have different meanings.

Comment: Consider *amalgam*.